# Upper central series on groups

Tags: group-theory

I have a problem which I think is harder to explain than trying to ask if my solution would actually work. Let $G$ be a group and suppose I have an hypothesis that only works for factors of a principal (also called chief) series which have finte order.

In general, does the upper central series is principal? I'm guessing it isn't, in that case, is there more than one way to refine it? Is there a group which has an upper central series in which every factor (or at least most of them) have infinite order?

By the order of the factor I mean that if $$\ldots\subseteq K\subseteq H\subseteq\ldots$$ is part of a principal series, then $|H/K|$ is finite.

Because in that case I can't apply the hypothesis at all, at least I can't see it going somewhere.

If there is some terminology I should define, please tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am finding it difficult to understand exactly what you are asking, but in any abelian group, finite or infinite, the upper central series is just $1 < G$, which is clearly not always a chief series.

Comment: Ok, I'll try my best to explain more but I'll give it one more try before saying exactly what I am trying to prove, sorry for the inconvenience:

The hypothesis I have on an arbitrary group $G$ only applies to factors of a chief series which are divisible by a prime $p$. I want to apply that hypothesis to the upper central series, but in general I don't even know if that is one of those.

As I imagine that in general, the upper central series is not a chief one, can it be refined to become one?

If I am being too ambiguous probably I'll make another post with the problem itself explaining more

Comment: It depends on what you mean by a principal series or chief series. In general infinite groups (like the infinite cyclic group) do not have a finite chief series.